# wait until all images have loaded after appending

Tags: jquery

I loop through a json file calling a function `loadContent` for each item. The function appends an `img` populating the src attribute at the same time. How can I wait untill all images have loaded after this loop to perform another action?

```
json.data.map(function(product) {
    loadContent(product);
});

function loadContent(product) {
    $("[data-product-pid-thumb=" + product.id + "]").append('<img src=' + product.image_groups[0].images[0].link + ' />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with promises like

```
var promises = json.data.map(function (product) {
    return markAvailable(product, lookRequestId);
});
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
    //do your stuff here
})

function markAvailable(product, lookRequestId) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var $img = $('<img src=' + product.image_groups[0].images[0].link + ' />').appendTo(".qv-overlay-container-" + lookRequestId + " [data-product-pid-thumb=" + product.id + "]");
    $img.on('load error', function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    })
    return deferred.promise();
}
```